# Parsing XML in R, struggling with different rows error

Tags: r, xml

I figure this question may have been asked before, but after research I couldn't find anything. I am new to parsing XML documents. I am trying to parse an XML page that looks like this:

```
schedule = xmlParse("MYXML.XML")

# here's what schedule looks like
<all-games>
  <game-schedule>
    <team name="Knicks">
    <outcome winner="OtherTeam">
  </game-schedule>
  <game-schedule>
    <team name="Lakers">
    <outcome winner="HomeTeam">
  </game-schedule>
  <game-schedule>
    <team name="Celtics">
  </game-schedule>
</all-games>


# here's my code to parse the XML
my_df = data.frame(
  team = sapply(schedule["//game-schedule/team/@name"], as, "character"),
  winner = sapply(schedule["//game-schedule/outcome/@winner"], as, "character")
)
```

and I get the following expected error (expected because there is no 3rd :

```
Error in data.frame(Visitor = sapply(schedule["//game-schedule/team/@name"],  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2
```

I would like to parse the dataframe such that missing children are simply filled in as NA. That is, I am trying to get the following dataframe:

```
my_df
      team      winner
1   Knicks   OtherTeam
2   Lakers    HomeTeam
3  Celtics          NA
```

The NA reflects in the XML document that the game hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a wrapper that can return NA if the tag is missing, something like `xpath2` below for `xpathSApply`.   Then get the nodes and apply `xpath2` anywhere at the current node ".//"

```
xpath2 <-function(x, ...){
    y <- xpathSApply(x, ...)
    ifelse(length(y) == 0, NA,  paste(y, collapse=", "))
}
nd <- getNodeSet(schedule, "//game-schedule")   
data.frame(
   team = sapply(nd, xpath2, ".//team", xmlGetAttr, "name"),
 winner = sapply(nd, xpath2, ".//outcome", xmlGetAttr, "winner")
)   
team    winner
1  Knicks OtherTeam
2  Lakers  HomeTeam
3 Celtics      <NA>
```